# URL / Templating system advice

Tags: templates, urls

I am trying to set up my blog so that the following URL pattern:

```
http://myblog.com/category/somecategory/
```

Will use the template file category.php

I have created the template, however, when I access the URL, I just get the template front-page.php (I'm not being redirected - the URL in the address bar is still http://myblog.com/category/somecategory/)

The links to the category pages are being auto-generated by the Categories widget and each category has at least one post in it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. Could you try to clarify?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have:

1. A category `somecategory` defined?
2. Posts categorized with `somecategory`?
3. Some default `else:` content in the Loop in `category.php`?

I suspect the URL is returning a 404, and WordPress is simply serving up the root URL, because it has no content to serve up from `category.php`.

**EDIT**

You don't need to *do anything special* to get WordPress to use the `category.php` template. It is a built-in part of the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display). You simply need to have a category created, and have Posts *in* that category.

**EDIT 2**

Can you try resetting your permalinks?

Do you have a live site link, so we can see the problem in action?

What is the markup of your `category.php` template file? Can you post it?

Comment: I've updated the question based on your response.

Comment: See updated answer; have a few more questions for you.